# How to use a return from a function?

Tags: php

I have a while loop in my content.php and I want to use $result like a parameter. How can i call a function from content.php file and get $result to use in my while loop?

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $ename = stripslashes($row['name']);
                    $eemail = stripslashes($row['email']);
                    $ebox = stripslashes($row['lund']);
                    $ecategori = stripslashes($row['LundaBlogg']);
                    $epost = stripslashes($row['post']);
                    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=".md5(strtolower($eemail))."&size=70";

                    echo
                    (
                        '<li> 
                            <div class="datum">'.$row['date'].'</div>
                            <div class="meta"><img src="'.$grav_url.'" alt="Gravatar" /><p>'.$ename.'</p></div>
                            </br>
                            <div class="categori"><p>Kategori: '.$ecategori.'</p></div>
                            <div class="topic"><p>'.$ebox.'</p></div>   
                            <div class="shout"><p>'.$epost.'</p></div>
                            <div class="raderaknapp"><a href="../delete_ac.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"class=\"icon-2 info-tooltip\">Radera Inlägg</a></div>
                            <div class="raportpost"><p><a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Rapportera inlägg</a></p></div>
                        </li>'
                    );

                    ?>
                        <h4>
                        <form action="<?php echo $self?>" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/>
                            <input type = "submit" name="Gilla" value = 'Gilla'"/>
                        </form>
                        </h4>

                        <div id="radera-infotwo">
                            <span onmouseover="ShowText('Messagetwo'); return true;" onmouseout="HideText('Messagetwo'); return true;" href="javascript:ShowText('Messagetwo')">
                                <img src="http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/post-images/20081107_6718_question-mark.gif">
                            </span>
                        </div>  

                        <div id="radera-info">
                            <span onmouseover="ShowText('Message'); return true;" onmouseout="HideText('Message'); return true;" href="javascript:ShowText('Message')">
                                <img src="http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/post-images/20081107_6718_question-mark.gif">
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <?
                        ?>
                    <?

                    echo ("Antal Gilla: " .$row['likes']); 

                    if(isset($_POST['Gilla']) && $_POST['id'] == $row['id']){echo '<h5><img src="../images/tummen-upp.png"/>Du har Gillat detta inlägg.</h5>';}

                    echo "<hr>";  
                }
```

This is my functions.php file where I have my function blogPosts_get()

```
function blogPosts_get(){ 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8;";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<p class="error">Wrong.</p>');   
}
```

I have tried with a return in my function blogPosts_get(), but I can not understand how its work. Can somebody help me get the $result variabel from my function blogPosts_get() so I can use It in my while loop?

Comment: What's the problem with `return $result;`?

Comment: @Barmar When I use result i get this error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/MAMP/web/blogg/pages/content.php on line 70

Comment: Are you doing `$result = blogPosts_get();` in the main code?

Comment: @Barmar Yes Im using $result = blogPosts_get(); in my content.php file, buy I get the same error like before

Comment: Then that error shouldn't happen. `blogPosts_get()` can never return `null` if it does `result $result;`, because it will call `die()` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include your functions.php  inside content.php using `require_once(./'your path'/functions.php');` and it should be at the beginning of your file content.php to be loaded before all then modify your code in functions.php as:

```
function blogPosts_get(){ 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8;";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<p class="error">Wrong.</p>');  
return $result; 
}
```

when you call it before the loop in content.php as follow:

```
$result = blogPosts_get();
```

Comment: @Bruno Chavez you're welcome, nice to help

Answer (score 0):

First off, the easy way is to modify the function to get the results AND build an array object for you to work with rather than returning a MySQL Query Object.

```
function blogPosts_get(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result)
        return array();
    else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            $posts[] = $row;
       return $posts;
   }  
}
```

This will handle getting the posts and will always return an array object for you to work with.

Next you have to make sure you're including the functions with `require` or `require_once`. You can call this by

```
$posts = blogPosts_get();
```

Then use a

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
```

**NOTICE**: MySQL_* has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO.

Comment: You've removed his error reporting!

Comment: He could check the size of the array or modify as such for his likings.

Comment: An empty result is not the same thing as an error from `mysql_query()`.

Comment: `return array('error' => mysql_error());` would do the trick with a check of `isset($posts['error']);`

Comment: @UnholyRanger Thanks for the NOTICE info I will check on that